# iOS - multiple http requests - do something after all is fetched

Tags: ios, design-patterns, asynchronous, restkit

I am using RestKit and I have following method. I have multiple requests in it and now I am thinking what is best approach (pattern maybe) to do something (for example hide loading alert) after all requests are done. I can set some global boolean values and in every request after it's done change it's own boolean value and check others if are done and then do something. But I am looking for some better solution. Are there some better way?

```
- (void)loadTypes
{
    RKObjectManager *restManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [restManager getObjectsAtPath:@"remarkGetCategories"
                       parameters:nil
                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
         GetTypesResponse *response = [statuses firstObject];
         categoryArray = response.Data;
         [_tableView reloadData];
     }
                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];

         NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
     }];

    [restManager getObjectsAtPath:@"remarkGetTypes"
                       parameters:nil
                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
         GetTypesResponse *response = [statuses firstObject];
         typeArray = response.Data;
         [_tableView reloadData];

     }
                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
     }];

    [restManager getObjectsAtPath:@"remarkGetSubTypes"
                       parameters:nil
                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
         GetTypesResponse *response = [statuses firstObject];
         subtypeArray = response.Data;
         [_tableView reloadData];

     }
                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
     }];

    [restManager getObjectsAtPath:@"transactionAccounts"
                       parameters:nil
                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
     {
         NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
         GetTypesResponse *response = [statuses firstObject];
         NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         for (id object in response.Data) {
             BankAccount *bankAccount = [[BankAccount alloc] init];
             [bankAccount setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:object];
             [mutableArray addObject:bankAccount];
         }
         accountArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
         [_tableView reloadData];

     }
                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
         NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

**Edit:**
Using ReactiveCocoa (RAC) for first method (`remarkGetCategories`). This is my helper class for RAC:
@implementation ReactiveCocoaHelper

```
+ (RACSignal *)signalGetCategories {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id <RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        RKObjectManager *restManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
        [restManager getObjectsAtPath:@"remarkGetCategories"
                           parameters:nil
                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
         {
             [subscriber sendNext:mappingResult];
             [subscriber sendCompleted];
         }
                              failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             [subscriber sendError:error];
         }];
        return nil; // `nil` means there's no way to cancel.
    }];
}

@end
```

This is my code for loading data:

```
RACSignal *signalCategories = [ReactiveCocoaHelper signalGetCategories];
[[RACSignal
  merge:@[ signalCategories ]]
 subscribeCompleted:^{
     NSLog(@"They're both done!");
     [_HUD hide:YES];
 }];
```

It's okay and I guess it would be working the way I want when I implement for all methods but for now I am not sure where and how to map result from request to my `categoryArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa), it has an example especially for cases like this, it's the 6th code chunk in the [Introduction section](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#introduction). It may seem complicated first, but it worth the effort of taking the time, it can seriously improve productivity, simplicity and stability.

Comment: Thanks for this, I looks like what I want. I tried it and I hope I am using it right. I added code in my question and I am just not sure how to map result from signal to my categoriesArray. If you could help me with this too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From a RestKit point of view, the `restManager` has an `operationQueue` parameter. So, in the success block you can check the `operationCount` to determine if all of the download and mapping operations are complete.